# Managing mutliple Amazon EC2 instances with Puppet

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet

I'm working with multiple instances (10 and more), and I want to configure them without accessing to each of them. Currently I look through Puppet and it seems is what I need. I've tried it for two instances and it's ok, but I installed puppet manually in both of instances, and also manually sent certificate from agent via `puppet agent`. Is there any way to install puppet automatically and send certificate for each node, not accessing them?

Comment: You can create an AMI with puppet installed, then spin new instances of that up. You can use user data to write bash scripts that will run when an instance is created, and you could also roll your own script to push out certificates if needed

Comment: Are AMI customizeable? I haven't seen that option yet

Comment: Absolutely, but you need to SSH into the EC2 instance, setup your custom stuff then create an AMI from that instances current state

Comment: problem is that we are using instances for running Spark Cluster, and these instances are generated by `spark-ec2` script. It uses predefined AMI

Comment: `spark-ec2 --ami [ami id]` can be used to specify a custom ami

Comment: Also, for managing AWS itself, have a look at https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/aws

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripts within UserData to autoconfigure your instance (see [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts)) by installing puppet, configuring it, and running it. Keep in mind that UserData is normally limited to 16kb and that data in there is stored base-64 encoded.

You can also build your own AMI with configuration scripts that run on boot, and then use that to download configuration from a central server, or read it out of userdata (e.g. `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data | bash -s`).

For example this is something we had in our Cloudformation template that installed a configuration service on our hosts.

```
"UserData": { "Fn::Base64" :  { "Fn::Join" : [ "\n", [
  "#!/bin/sh",
  "curl -k -u username:password -f -s -o /etc/init.d/ec2 https://scriptserver.example.com/scripts/ec2",
  "chmod a+x /etc/init.d/ec2",
  "/etc/init.d/ec2 start"] ] } }
```

Ideally the 'scriptserver' is in the same VPC since the username and password aren't terribly secure (they're stored unencrypted on the machine, the script server, and in the Cloudformation and EC2 services).

The advantage of bootstrapping everything with userdata instead of building an AMI is flexibility. You can update your bootstrap scripts, generate new instances, and you're done. The disadvantages are speed since you'll have wait for everything to install and configure each time an instance launches (beware Cloudformation timeouts) and stability since if your script installs packages from a public repository (e.g. apt-get install mysql), the packages can be updated at any time, potentially introducing untested software into your environment. The workaround for the latter is to install software from locations you control.

Comment: how do you differentiate different servers?